# how can i execute codes sequentially only after firebase is done uploading a file in android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I have a function for uploading single picture called firebaseUploadPicture. It is called multiple times in uploadUserData() which is then called in createNewUserAndUploadDocuments function. And then there is some code that needs to be executed sequentially which sets the view to some other layout and initiates a home button.

```
 register.setOnClickListener{
        val validated: Boolean = validateTextFields(fullName) && validateTextFields(email) && validateTextFields(password) &&
                validateTextFields(repassword) && validateTextFields(phoneNumber) && validateTextFields(DOB)
                && validatePicturesSelected(ctznPictureFront) && validatePicturesSelected(ctznPictureBack) && validatePicturesSelected(studentIdFront) && validatePicturesSelected(studentIdBack)
                && validatePicturesSelected(profilePicture) &&  validateTermsAndConditions(termAgreement) && validateMatchPasswords(password,repassword)
        if(validated==true)createNewUserAndUploadDocuments() //this has to hold
         
        setContentView(R.layout.registration_finished) //this block has to execute sequentially
        val homeButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnHome) //this block has to execute 
        homeButton.setOnClickListener { //this block has to execute 
        val intent = Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java) //this block has to execute 
        startActivityIfNeeded(intent,0) //this block has to execute 
        finish() //this block has to execute 
    } //this block has to execute 


    }
   private fun uploadUserData(uid: String){
    val pictures = arrayListOf("Profile Picture","Citizenship Front","Citizenship Back","Student Id Front", "Student Id Back")
    val registrationPictureUpload = UserPictureUploader(user.uid.toString())


    registrationPictureUpload.firebaseUploadPicture(this,user.profilePictureUri, "profilePicture",pictures.get(0))
    registrationPictureUpload.firebaseUploadPicture(this, user.ctznFUri, "ctznFront",pictures.get(1))
    registrationPictureUpload.firebaseUploadPicture(this, user.ctznBUri, "ctznBack",pictures.get(2))
    registrationPictureUpload.firebaseUploadPicture(this, user.stdIdFUri, "stdIdF",pictures.get(3))
    registrationPictureUpload.firebaseUploadPicture(this, user.stdIdBUri, "stdIdB",pictures.get(4))

   

}

class UserPictureUploader(val uid:String){
        fun firebaseUploadPicture(context: Context, uri: Uri, filename: String,dialogTitle:String){
            var picture = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("new_registration/$uid/${filename}.jpg")
            val pd:ProgressDialog
            pd = ProgressDialog(context)
            pd.setTitle("Uploading ${dialogTitle}")
            pd.setCancelable(false)
            pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
            pd.show()

            picture.putFile(uri).addOnProgressListener {task ->
                pd.setMessage( "${100 * task.bytesTransferred / task.totalByteCount }% of 100% completed")
            }.addOnCompleteListener{
                pd.dismiss()

            }
        }

}
```

Note i cannot use nested OnCompleteListners. There has to be a way to hold the function with firebase instance and execute the rest of the codes sequentially.

Comment: Any code that needs data from the Storage, needs to be inside the onComplete method, or be called from there. Have you tried to do that way?

Comment: thats ok. I just cannot run the code blockingly so that all the statements next to if(validated==true)createNewUserAndUploadDocuments() happens sequentially. right now it just gets executed without letting uploads to finish

Comment: thank you for your valuable answer. i will surely note that.